# Bluetooth traffic and snort integration

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

is it possible to capture Bluetooth traffic from beacons and analyse its information by any means ? can this be later integrated in to snort to detect any tampering done to it ? any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Your question is to broad. What kind of application are you trying to build? What language are you using? Maybe with more details people can help you answering your question.

Comment: @GustavoStraube I am working on building an intrusion detection system in IOT environment , using two protocols wireless and Bluetooth smart , I am starting by analyzing both kinds of traffic using tools like wireshark etc later I would like to integrate all in snort , I am looking for pointers as to how i should proceed about it .